# Division line in polydiv not correct

Tags: polynom

Line in division is not as expected...while using **polydiv**

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage[paperwidth=94mm,paperheight=50mm,margin=2mm,footskip=2mm
] {geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polydiv}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\PolySet{p}{1,0,-4,1,3}
\PolySet{g}{1,0,-3}
\[
\PolyLongDiv{p}{g}
\]
\end{document}
```

How to correct it?
[image]